# Incorrect promise response in mobile browsers and Internet explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm having issues to get the successful response from a promise when running the application on a mobile phone (using chrome browser) and when using internet explorer 11 on a desktop. 
Can anybody give me a hand on this?

The response of the promise when using chrome on a desktop is correct.

In my code I have a factory used to retrieve a promise:

```
menus.factory('StaticDataService', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    return{
        getStaticData: function (id, date) {
            return $resource('http://10.0.0.158:8080/rev/rest/json/businessunit/:id/roster/staticData/:date')
                .get({id: id, date: date}).$promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

To retrieve the data I have a separated service that does:

```
 var staticDataPromise = StaticDataService.getStaticData(1569, today);

 var staticData = staticDataPromise.then(function onSuccess(response){
      return response.toJSON().staticData;
  });
```

When running the application from a desktop, using Chrome, the response that I receive is the promise resolved that inside contains the statidData object that I'm expecting:

```
 $promise: d 
 $resolved: true 
 staticData: Object
 __proto__: e
```

When running the same application from a mobile phone (I'm doing a remote debugging) or from internet explorer 11, what I receive as a response is a promise resolved but instead of having the staticData object it has an array of 3800 characters:

```
0: "<"
1: "!"
2: "D" 
3: "O"
4: "C"
5: "T"
6: "Y"
7: "P"
8: "E"
9: " "
10: "H" 
[...]
$promise: d
$resolved: true
__proto__: e
```

Am I doing something wrong? or the promises need an special treatment on Internet Explorer and mobile browsers? Please someone help me :)

Comment: Inspect the actual response body in IE11 developer tools network tab. It's an html file , my bet it's something like a 404 page.

Comment: Yes it is an html file but it is not an error page, looks like it is the login page. I have other components in the screen and they load, and also I've added an error handler in the promise but it is not reached.

Comment: Well that was the error... I was accessing to the page without been logged in in the application from the other browsers so I was receiving the login page html as a response :/

Comment: Need to tweak server so it sends you different status for api calls that you can then intercept and push user to login page